# Issues with useReducer not synchronously updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to `React` docs :

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex
>   state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
>   depends on the previous one.

**1.** can somebody explain me why `useReducer` is not updating the state synchronously ?

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if( action.type === 'ADD_VALUE') {
        console.log(`STATE IN REDUCER`, [...state, action.path]) // => ["1.1"]
        return [...state, action.path]
    }   
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [])

<input type="button" onClick={() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ADD_VALUE', path: "1.1"})
    console.log(`STATE`, state) // => []
    // here i want to do some stuff based on the lastest updated state (["1.1"] and not [])
    // for example dispatch an action with redux
}}/>
```

**2.** How can I do some stuff (dispatch a redux action) based on the lastest updated state (`["1.1"]` and not `[]`) ?

Comment: The state is not updated synchronously, and even if it was React will not mutate the current state, so `state` is a reference to the previous state.

Comment: Because [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). 99.9% sure using hooks doesn't change that. Also, as @Tholle said, the `state` you're referring to would be stale anyway.

Comment: @Tholle and how to solve that (look at the second part in the question)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how to solve it then ?

Comment: @Youssef - Your component will get rerendered when the state changes. So just render according to state, as usual.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no i'm using it to update other component not the current one

Comment: @T.J.Crowder because i will dispatch an redux action

Answer (score 13):

Use `useEffect` to access the state correctly. You could add some safe-guarding if you want something invoking if a certain criterion is hit.

If you want to access your reducer across components, you can store the reducer using Context API. Look below for an example. You can see the reducer being injected into the Context on the parent component and then two child components that a) dispatches an action b) receives the update from the action.

**1. Example of context reducer to use across multiple components**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Application = React.createContext({
  state: null,
  dispatch: null
});

function ActionComponent() {
  const { dispatch } = React.useContext(Application);
  return (
      <div>
          <div>Action Component</div>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch("lol")}>Do something</button>
      </div>
  );
}

function ListenerComponent() {
  const { state } = React.useContext(Application);
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      console.log(state);
    },
    [state]
  );
  return <div>Listener Component</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(function(state = [], action) {
    return [...state, action];
  });
  return (
    <Application.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      <div className="App">
        <ActionComponent />
        <ListenerComponent />
      </div>
    </Application.Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**2. Example of local reducer without using Application Context**

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if( action.type === 'ADD_VALUE') {
        return [...state, action.path]
    }   
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [])

React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
}, [state]);

<input type="button" onClick={() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ADD_VALUE', path: "1.1"})
}}/>
```

Comment: thanks @Win for this hint it will help me in the future, but i have the `dispatch`inside a loop so i don't think this solution will be suitable for my case don't you think ?

Comment: @Youssef it doesn't matter, I'll show you an example of how to talk to the same reducer from different components

Comment: Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Perhaps you could make your examples runnable?

Comment: @Youssef It does not matter if it's in a loop as the action is sent to a queue and the listener will receive the updated state once this loop has completed.

Comment: thanks a lot @Win i will take a look deeply in this and i will give you feedback