# custom react useReducer hook state did't update in a component when b component dispatched the update method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

my custom react hook useModalState write with useReducer's state did't update in a component when b component dispatched the update method.I have checked a similar question on stackoverflow [Issues with useReducer not synchronously updating the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301495/issues-with-usereducer-not-synchronously-updating-the-state) but I don't think that answer it'll work for me,so I pasted code below.
useModal.tsx:

```
//useModal.tsx code
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

interface ModalToggleStatus {
  isAddOpen: boolean;
  isEditOpen: boolean;
  isImportOpen: boolean;
  closeAdd: () => void;
  closeEdit: () => void;
  closeImport: () => void;
  openImport: () => void;
  openAdd: () => void;
  openEdit: () => void;
}

enum modalActionTypes {
  OPEN_ADD = 'OPEN_ADD',
  CLOSE_ADD = 'CLOSE_ADD',
  OPEN_EDIT = 'OPEN_EDIT',
  CLOSE_EDIT = 'CLOSE_EDIT',
  OPEN_IMPORT = 'OPEN_IMPORT',
  CLOSE_IMPORT = 'CLOSE_IMPORT',
  RETSET = 'RESET',
}

export const ModalToggleContext = React.createContext<ModalToggleStatus>({
  isAddOpen: false,
  isEditOpen: false,
  isImportOpen: false,
  closeAdd: () => {},
  closeEdit: () => {},
  closeImport: () => {},
  openImport: () => {},
  openAdd: () => {},
  openEdit: () => {},
});

const useToggleModal = () => {
  const initialState = useContext(ModalToggleContext);

  const modalReducer = (
    state: ModalToggleStatus,
    action: { type: modalActionTypes }
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case modalActionTypes.OPEN_ADD:
        return {
          ...state,
          isAddOpen: true,
          isEditOpen: false,
          isImportOpen: false,
        };
      case modalActionTypes.CLOSE_ADD:
        return { ...state, isAddOpen: false };
      case modalActionTypes.OPEN_EDIT:
        return {
          ...state,
          isEditOpen: true,
          isAddOpen: false,
          isImportOpen: false,
        };
      case modalActionTypes.CLOSE_EDIT:
        return { ...state, isEditOpen: false };
      case modalActionTypes.OPEN_IMPORT:
        return {
          ...state,
          isImportOpen: true,
          isAddOpen: false,
          isEditOpen: false,
        };
      case modalActionTypes.CLOSE_IMPORT:
        return { ...state, isImportOpen: false };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(modalReducer, initialState);

  const closeAdd = () => dispatch({ type: modalActionTypes.CLOSE_ADD });
  const closeEdit = () => dispatch({ type: modalActionTypes.CLOSE_EDIT });
  const openAdd = () => dispatch({ type: modalActionTypes.OPEN_ADD });
  const closeImport = () => dispatch({ type: modalActionTypes.CLOSE_IMPORT });
  const openImport = () => dispatch({ type: modalActionTypes.OPEN_IMPORT });
  const openEdit = () => dispatch({ type: modalActionTypes.OPEN_EDIT });
  const init = () => dispatch({ type: modalActionTypes.RETSET });

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  const value = {
    isAddOpen: state.isAddOpen,
    isEditOpen: state.isEditOpen,
    isImportOpen: state.isImportOpen,
    closeAdd,
    closeEdit,
    closeImport,
    openImport,
    openAdd,
    openEdit,
  };

  return value;
};

export default useToggleModal;

//there are two place dispatched the openEdit:
//first place
 const {
      isAddOpen,
      isEditOpen,
      isImportOpen,
      openAdd,
      openEdit,
      closeAdd,
      closeEdit,
      openImport,
      closeImport,
    } = useToggleModal();

  const handleRowDoubleClick = (e: React.SyntheticEvent, d: Data) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    openEdit();

    setCheckedIds([d.Id]);
    setEditItem(d.Id);
  };

             <TableRow
                key={index}
                onDoubleClick={(e) => handleRowDoubleClick(e, d)}
                sx={
                  !Reflect.ownKeys(d).includes('Funcs')
                    ? {
                        '&:hover': {
                          backgroundColor: '#aaa7a7',
                          color: '#fff',
                        },
                      }
                    : {}
                }
                onClick={(e) => handleChecked(e, d.Id!.toString())}
              >
//Seconde place

          <RoleButtons
            dataType={dataType}
            addHandler={() => openAdd()}
            editHandler={() => openEdit()}
            deleteHandler={handleDelete(checkedIds) as any}
            importHandler={() =>openImport()}
            exportHandler={handleExport}
          />

//And code dispatched closeEdit:
//I pass these Element using renderPorps to switch the different type of components

            <DicEdit
              initialValues={initialValues as DicValues}
              handleClose={() => closeEdit()}
            />`
```

Comment: How are you dispatching the actions in B?

Comment: just by passing the ()=>openEdit() or ()=>closeEdit() to  onClick.I've updated the code in the question,please take a look.@Nicholas Mberev.these code seems have a lot of preblem,I already replace the code by using redux,but it still have a slow time to open the modal component (2.56s).I am really caurious how the improve my code.